# tree comand - view only directories with size of each driectory

Tags: tree

I am trying to list only the directories using tree with the sizes

```
tree -d PATH_TO_FOLDER
```

but using du we can get the size

```
tree -d PATH_TO_FOLDER --du -h
```

but the above command does not include the size of all the files inside the directory

example:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxx:~$   tree -d /home/ubuntu/santhosh --du -h
[144K]  /home/ubuntu/santhosh
└── [140K]  covid_db
    ├── [ 72K]  mx
    │      ├── [ 28K]  deid
    │      │      ├── [ 20K]  download
    │      │      └── [4.0K]  files_list
    │      └── [ 40K]  link
    │             └── [ 36K]  download
    └── [ 64K]  rx
        ├── [ 24K]  deid
        │      └── [ 20K]  download
        └── [ 36K]  link
               └── [ 32K]  download
```

i can achieve what i want using du directly

```
ubuntu@xxxxxx:~$   du -ah /home/ubuntu/santhosh --max-depth=4 | sort -hr
957G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/
562G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx
474G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx/link/download
474G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx/link
395G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/rx
341G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/rx/link/download
341G    /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/rx/link
89G     /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx/deid/download
89G     /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx/deid
55G     /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/rx/deid/download
55G     /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/rx/deid
16K     /home/ubuntu/santhosh/covid_db/mx/deid/files_list
```

but I like the tree representaion

can someone let me konw how to achieve this using tree

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
find PATH_TO_FOLDER -type d -exec du {} \;
```